# How do I create a non-persistent programmatic timer in EJB 2.1 using TimedObject?

Tags: timer, ejb-2.x

I have looked up this question in many forums and the answers seem to apply only to EJB 3.1 with TimerConfig method.
Is there a similar way to create a  nonpersistent timer for EJB 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean an application server that supports the EJB 3.1 API with an ejb-jar.xml file that contains `version="2.1"`, then use `TimerConfig.setPersistent` as usual.

If you mean an application server that only supports the EJB 2 API, then no, there is no standard way to create a non-persistent timer.  Instead, you will need to use a non-standard solution like CommonJ or WebSphere AsynchBeans.